# Debian package name for Google's "gn" build tool?

Tags: debian, chromium

I'm trying to build Chromium from source, but it uses this build system called "gn" that is absolutely Google-proof because of its name.

What is this thing called in Debian's package manager?

Apparently, the source for "gn" is part of Chromium's source tree, but that doesn't help, since you need "gn" to build it.

Comment: Why google when you can [search the packages directly](https://packages.debian.org/en/)?

Comment: If it makes you feel any better I've had no luck finding a pre-compiled version, and even worse I appear to be too thick in the head to download it and compile it from scratch.  Maybe it's meant to be used only within the context of building Chromium?

Comment: See here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/tools/gn/docs/hacking.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think the easiest way to get this tool is through the chromium project and their build tools:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_build_instructions.md

This seems to have made it available for me:

`git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git`

`export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/depot_tools"`

Then, in my case, I was attempting to compile webrtc, and proceeded as follows:

`cd webrtc/src`

`gn gen out/Default`

`cd out/Default/`

`ninja`

And that yielded binaries in webrtc/src/out/Default

Answer (score 0):

It's not in Debian. Unfortunately. (Also, you can search for packages with `apt search gn`.)

I have found some instructions on building a standalone version of `gn`, though; but it's a bit involved.

https://gist.github.com/mohamed/4fa7eb75807463d4dfa3

Comment: It's actually bundled in Chromium's source tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building Chromium (or projects that require it as a dep), them @mpr's answer is right.

However, you don't have to pull in Chromium's depot_tools just to get the two binaries (gn, ninja) if you are using them for non-Chromium projects.

I noticed the experimental GN build for LLVM just use a URL to download the binaries without having to download Chromium's depot_tools: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/llvm/utils/gn/get.py